# Is there a way to create a non-rectangular UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I have buttons laid out diagonally with their image frames as shown in the picture below. How can I alter the corner points so the buttons don't significantly overlap?

[image]

I know I could just create a rectangular UIButton and rotate it, but I may eventually need custom-shaped buttons anyway. Also, my button images are essentially text with a transparent background, like shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way of doing anything other than rectangles.  In this case rotating it would work, but if you really want to get creative you can write your own class.  You can use polygons or other shapes and then test the touch to see if it lies within the shape or not.  Then you'll have to handle all the image switching and target/action stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single UIImageView with an image that looks like what you want. Then just use touchesBegan and go by the exact point where the touch occurs.